# how to delete record from persisted store when user deletes row in Datagridview

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am currently using this:

```
Private Sub PersonDataGridView_UserDeletingRow(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewRowCancelEventArgs) Handles PersonDataGridView.UserDeletingRow
            DBContext.Persons.Remove(e.Row.DataBoundItem)
End Sub
```

But this behaves strange: it sometimes deletes the right record, but then gives an error about index out of range (translated from Dutch: *error in Datagridview: index out of range: ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException*) afterwards;

Example: I have 5 rows in the datagridview; I delete row 3 using the above code, then rows 3 and 4 are removed from the datagridview. This causes an error when trying to save the DBcontext on that second deleted row, because it has not been set to "deleted" in the context...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use UserDeletedRow.  Using the UserDeletingRow, you are deleting record 3 from the data source as you want, but then the datagridview changes and it will fire the userdeletingrow again.

You want to perform the delete in the data source only after the record has been deleted from the gridview.